# class Facebook not found in laravel 5 facebook graph api

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, facebook-graph-api, laravel-5

I am using facebook graph api in laravel 5.1.I have installed it usnig composer command

```
composer require facebook/php-sdk-v4
```

the facebook graph api has been installed 
but when i create the facebook api object in laravel then it's give me this error

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Userapp\Facebook\Facebook' not found
```

it is in this line

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
```

here is my Controller file

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Userapp;
require_once( base_path('vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/autoload.php') );
// Facebook Requires
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
```

and the function of the controller

```
public function index()
    {   
        // init app with app id and secret
        $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
          'app_id' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
          'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
          'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
          //'default_access_token' => '{access-token}', // optional
        ]);


        try {
          // Get the Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser object for the current user.
          // If you provided a 'default_access_token', the '{access-token}' is optional.
          $response = $fb->get('/me', '{access-token}');
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
          // When Graph returns an error
          echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
          exit;
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
          // When validation fails or other local issues
          echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
          exit;
        }

        $me = $response->getGraphUser();
        echo 'Logged in as ' . $me->getName();
    }
```

kindly help me solving this problem.
i will really appreciate that 
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within the index function, you are not in the global scope so that as you call the class as `Facebook\Facebook`, PHP thinks that you are calling `Facebook\Facebook` declared in the `App\Http\Controllers\Userapp` namespace.

Either you need to reference them as globally like below with prepending `\`.

```
public function index()
{
    $fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([]);
    // your code
    catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e)
    // your code
    catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e)
    // your code
}
```

Or use the aliases.

```
use Facebook\Facebook as Facebook;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException as FacebookResponseException
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException as FacebookSDKException

public function index()
{
    $fb = new Facebook([]);
    // your code
    catch(FacebookResponseException $e)
    // your code
    catch(FacebookSDKException $e)
    // your code
 }
```

Comment: Thanks  Burak  i am in office now i will check it after some time and will let you about this code

Comment: Burak i am using use Facebook\FacebookSession as FacebookSession; and using FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('xxxx', 'xxxx'); but it says Class 'Facebook\FacebookSession' not found

Comment: can you check whether the autoload file is loaded or not? line 1: `ob_start();` line 2: `require_once( base_path('vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/autoload.php') );` line 3: `$output = ob_get_contents();  // check if this empty or not` line 4: `echo empty($output) ? 'not loaded' : 'loaded'; ` line 5: `ob_end_clean();`

Comment: Burak it is printing nothing could you please help me on this

Comment: @usama nothing? you mean it's not printing not loaded or loaded out?

Comment: sorry for the late reply yes its  also does not  echo anything to

Comment: i have create a variable and stored the condition result in a variable now it then echo the varivable below the ob then it show "not loaded"

Comment: then check the path whether the file exists at the exact location as it seems like failing on including the autoloader file.

Comment: here is my directory where autoload file is present E:\xampp\htdocs\jay_old\laravel\vendor\facebook\php-sdk-v4\src\Facebook   
and here is path which is genrated by require autoload statement 
E:\xampp\htdocs\jay_old\laravel\vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/autoload.php

Comment: Ah, you are on Windows, that's why you are facing with that issue, you should better check the [homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/master/homestead) out. Anyway, the reason that you fail is the slashes in Windows as you can see the difference between the expected value and the value you get, instead use `require_once( base_path(join(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array('vendor', 'facebook', 'php-sdk-v4', 'src', 'Facebook', 'autoload.php' )))`;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94669/discussion-between-usama-and-burak).